# server sent event handler not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, handler, server-sent-events

I have problem in my site

I need push notification and I use server sent event javascript and `Handler.ashx`.

My `NotificationHandler.ashx`:

```
public class NotificationHandler : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
{
    public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";
        context.Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";

        var _json = new JsonStringSerializer();
        var _chat = new ChatManager();

        while (true)
        {
            var GetStorage = _chat.GetStorage();
            var GetJson = _json.SerializeToString<ChatUserStorage>(GetStorage);

            context.Response.Write(string.Format("data: {0}\n\n", GetJson));
            context.Response.Flush();

            if (context.Response.IsClientConnected == false)
            {
                break;
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }

    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

JavaScript :

```
function ServerSentNotification() {

sourceEventSource = new EventSource('/services/NotificationHandler.ashx', { retry: 1000 });

sourceEventSource.addEventListener("open", function (event) {
}, false);

sourceEventSource.addEventListener("error", function (event) {
    if (event.eventPhase == EventSource.CLOSED) {
    }
}, false);

sourceEventSource.addEventListener("message", function (event) {

    UpdateProgress(event.data);
}, false);
```

}

All request stuck my page and another ajax poll not working request waiting.

I use web application framework 4.0

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: chrome. and u can check example http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_internet/displaying-real-time-data-using-html5-and-asp.net.htm

Comment: when i add while loop this is stuck my page and i cant do anyting